# Schedule a Lync meeting from Sharepoint App programatically with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online

It´s posible to schedule a lync meeting programatically with JSOM from a Sharepoint Hosted App?

Comment: Are you using Lync Online? I noticed you tagged SharePoint Online.  Does this mean you do not have an On Prem Lync server?

Comment: Yes, I am developing a Sharepoint App in Sharepoint online on Office 365, that creates events in the site calendar. 

If the user select Lync meeting in the event type, i need to schedule a lync meeting with Lync Online.

Comment: Lync's REST API is called UCWA, and unfortunately, it is not available for Lync Online, only On Prem: https://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/what-is-lync-ucwa-api